# Bundle ImageMagick library with OS X App?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, imagemagick

I am developing an OS X application, and would like to use ImageMagick to do some image manipulation. I have noticed that the CLI ImageMagick utilities require some environment variables to work. Is it possible to bundle the ImageMagick suite of tools with my application and use them in my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here is my solution:

I bundled the [OS X binary](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) release with my project, and used an NSTask to call the binaries. You need to specify the "MAGICK_HOME" and "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" environment variables for NSTask to work correctly. Here is snippet of what I am using.

Note that this example is hard coded to use the "composite" command ... and uses hard coded arguments, but you can change it to whatever you like ... it is just serving as a proof of concept.

```
-(id)init
{
    if ([super init])
    {
        NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString* imageMagickPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Contents/Resources/ImageMagick"];
        NSString* imageMagickLibraryPath = [imageMagickPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/lib"];
    
        MAGICK_HOME = imageMagickPath;
        DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = imageMagickLibraryPath;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)composite
{
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    // the ImageMagick library needs these two environment variables.
    NSMutableDictionary* environment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [environment setValue:MAGICK_HOME forKey:@"MAGICK_HOME"];
    [environment setValue:DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH forKey:@"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"];

    // helper function from
    // http://www.karelia.com/cocoa_legacy/Foundation_Categories/NSFileManager__Get_.m
    NSString* pwd = [Helpers pathFromUserLibraryPath:@"MyApp"];

    // executable binary path
    NSString* exe = [MAGICK_HOME stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/bin/composite"];

    [task setEnvironment:environment];
    [task setCurrentDirectoryPath:pwd]; // pwd
    [task setLaunchPath:exe]; // the path to composite binary
    // these are just example arguments
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-gravity", @"center", @"stupid hat.png", @"IDR663.gif", @"bla.png", nil]];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
}
```

This solution bundles the bulk of the entire library with your release (37MB at the moment), so it might be less than ideal for some solutions, but it is working :-)

Answer (score 2):

Possible?  Yes.  Many apps have done so, but it can be tedious.

NSTask allows for custom environment variables.

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. Any help would be good AFAIK ImageMagick only supports absolute paths, so you can not use for example tilds in the path to it. So although NSTask works, I have only been apple to put the complied ImageMagick libraries in the "/" area of any HD I install the app on. There are APIs  MagickWand
MagickCore
PerlMagick
Magick++, But I have not been apple to figure them out yet!

Comment: I didnt know that NSTask allowed for environment variables ... I might be able to make this work :) If I figure out a solution I will post it here.

Comment: If ImageMagick builds dylibs, one trick might be to pass down DYLD_* environment variables.  However, you'd be much better off rebuilding the ImageMagick binaries and libraries to support embedding.   I know it has been done before, but I don't have details.  Google can help, I'm sure.