# ImageMagick in App bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I found [question (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773768/bundle-imagemagick-library-with-os-x-app) witch is very similar to my problem. And the code in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4792558/1428622) looks to be something I've been looking for for long time:

```
-(id)init
{
    if ([super init])
    {
        NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString* imageMagickPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Contents/Resources/ImageMagick"];
        NSString* imageMagickLibraryPath = [imageMagickPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/lib"];

        MAGICK_HOME = imageMagickPath;
        DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = imageMagickLibraryPath;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)composite
{
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    // the ImageMagick library needs these two environment variables.
    NSMutableDictionary* environment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [environment setValue:MAGICK_HOME forKey:@"MAGICK_HOME"];
    [environment setValue:DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH forKey:@"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"];

    // helper function from
    // http://www.karelia.com/cocoa_legacy/Foundation_Categories/NSFileManager__Get_.m
    NSString* pwd = [Helpers pathFromUserLibraryPath:@"MyApp"];

    // executable binary path
    NSString* exe = [MAGICK_HOME stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/bin/composite"];

    [task setEnvironment:environment];
    [task setCurrentDirectoryPath:pwd]; // pwd
    [task setLaunchPath:exe]; // the path to composite binary
    // these are just example arguments
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-gravity", @"center", @"stupid hat.png", @"IDR663.gif", @"bla.png", nil]];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
}
```

But when I try to use it I am having 6 errors:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'MAGICK_HOME'
Use of undeclared identifier 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'
Use of undeclared identifier 'MAGICK_HOME'
Use of undeclared identifier 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'
Use of undeclared identifier 'Helpers'
Use of undeclared identifier 'MAGICK_HOME'
```

[image]

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To use the code you linked, probably you just need to declare those as global variables.

```
NSString * MAGICK_HOME = nil;
NSString * DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = nil;

@implementation ...
```

Replace `Helpers` with `[self class]`, and add the function from the linked source:

```
/*
    NSFileManager: Get the path within the user's Library directory
    Original Source: <http://cocoa.karelia.com/Foundation_Categories/NSFileManager__Get_.m>
    (See copyright notice at <http://cocoa.karelia.com>)
*/

/*" Return the path in the user library path of the given sub-path.  In other words, if given inSubPath is "foo", the path returned will be /Users/myUser/Library/foo
"*/
-  (NSString *) pathFromUserLibraryPath:(NSString *)inSubPath
{
    NSArray *domains = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *baseDir= [domains objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *result = [baseDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:inSubPath];
    return result;
}
```